# The file "[file name]" is checked out or locked for editing even though no one has it open

Tags: document-library, check-out, lock

I get the following error when I try to check out a document from a document library in SharePoint that has been recently edited:

> The file "[file name]" is checked out or locked for editing by
>   "[username]"

I don't understanding why I'm getting this error because I just recently checked in the document under the username mentioned above and it does not show up as being checked out in the UI.

How can it be that this file is checked out/locked for editing?

Comment: See also [Clearing a Short-Term File Lock](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/42999/clearing-short-term-file-lock/169498)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I ended up finding my answer on the Microsoft Support pages.  It turns out if the user selected "Edit in [client application name]" to edit the document then after they check it in there is a **10 minute delay** before the write lock on the document is released.  Below is a link to the support page where I found my answer.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/899709

Answer (score 3):

You might want to try:
From the document library > Settings > Document Library settings > Manage checked out files

Answer (score 2):

In our case, the answer was to clear the Credential Manager entry.  Visit the below URL.

http://www.sharepointindepth.com/the-file-is-locked-for-shared-use-by/

Answer (score 1):

If you have Microsoft Office Upload Center installed on your local system then consider clearing cache from settings. Everything should work fine.

optionally, you can create a action to release the lock programatically.

Answer (score -1):

If you do not want to wait 10 minutes, the real solution is here

https://sharepointobservations.wordpress.com/2013/09/10/remove-sharepoint-client-side-file-lock/

Comment: Explain the solution, not just link somewhere else.