# Locked for Shared Use?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation

I just uploaded a Microsoft Word Document to SharePoint 2013.

When I first tried to `Check Out` the Word Document I got a message stating

```
it was locked for shared use.
```

Then it suddenly allowed me to `Check Out`. I'm not sure what happened. What did it mean by locked for shared use?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's may be a credential manager cache issue ,

[image]

So Try to

- Clear Your Browser Cache and Restart Your Browser
- Clear Your Cache in Credential Manager as mentioned [here](http://www.sharepointindepth.com/sharepoint-prompts-for-credentials-three-times-followed-by-a-blank-white-page/#credman)

Check more details at [The file {filename} is locked for shared use by {user}](http://www.sharepointindepth.com/the-file-is-locked-for-shared-use-by/)

Comment: Clearing browser cache has resolved this issue for me in the past.  Additionally, this earlier post provides instructions and a script for clearing the lock via PowerShell:  http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/42999/clearing-short-term-file-lock

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by editing the Share permissions on the file itself:

1. Stop inheriting permissions
2. Remove access from all groups except SP Admins

I was then able to delete the file.

Answer (score 0):

I checked for sync issues first and cleared those, specifically one that required the user to entered her credentials, although this was fixed by simply opening and closing the file. 
Then clearing the cache in the browser did the trick for me!